# how can an AsyncTask wait for another without deadLock

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, notify

I'm trying to implement 2 Async Tasks where one should wait for the other to finish.

I make a test case for it, that looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    public static boolean SYNCING = false;
    public static Object LOCK = new Object();

    public static void setSync(){
        Log.i(TAG, "setting Sync=true");
        synchronized (LOCK) {
            SYNCING = true;
        }
    }

    public static void waitForSync(){
        Log.i(TAG, "waiting for Sync");
        synchronized (LOCK) {
            try{
                while (SYNCING){
                    LOCK.wait();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ignore){}
        }
    }

    public static void setSyncFinish(){
        Log.i(TAG, "setSyncFinish to notify all");
        synchronized (LOCK) {
            SYNCING = false;
            LOCK.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public class WaitingOnLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground of WaitingForLoaderTask");

            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }

            waitForSync();
            Log.i(TAG, "finishedWaiting!");
            return null;
        }

    }

    public class LoaderTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        long mRuntime;
        int mTimes;

        public LoaderTask(long runtime, int times){
            mRuntime = runtime;
            mTimes = times;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            while(mTimes >= 0){
                Log.i(TAG, "sleeping for " + mTimes + " times for " + mRuntime + " milliseconds");
                mTimes--;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(mRuntime);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.e("MainActivity", "Interrupted", e);
                }
            }

            setSyncFinish();

            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

But I can't get the `WaitingOnLoaderTask` to wait correctly. if I run this in onCreate

```
new WaitingOnLoaderTask().execute((Void[])null);
new LoaderTask(1000, 5).execute((Void[])null);
```

I get a logOutput like this (a DeadLock happens):

```
03-08 18:17:23.309: I/myUniqueLogTag(4432): setting Sync=true
03-08 18:17:23.317: I/myUniqueLogTag(4432): doInBackground of WaitingForLoaderTask
03-08 18:17:23.817: I/myUniqueLogTag(4432): waiting for Sync
```

and on

```
new LoaderTask(1000, 5).execute((Void[])null);
new WaitingOnLoaderTask().execute((Void[])null);
```

i get a Log like this:

```
03-08 18:18:53.082: I/myUniqueLogTag(4621): sleeping for 5 times for 1000 milliseconds
03-08 18:18:54.082: I/myUniqueLogTag(4621): sleeping for 4 times for 1000 milliseconds
03-08 18:18:55.090: I/myUniqueLogTag(4621): sleeping for 3 times for 1000 milliseconds
03-08 18:18:56.082: I/myUniqueLogTag(4621): sleeping for 2 times for 1000 milliseconds
03-08 18:18:57.090: I/myUniqueLogTag(4621): sleeping for 1 times for 1000 milliseconds
03-08 18:18:58.106: I/myUniqueLogTag(4621): sleeping for 0 times for 1000 milliseconds
03-08 18:18:59.113: I/myUniqueLogTag(4621): doInBackground of WaitingForLoaderTask
03-08 18:18:59.113: I/myUniqueLogTag(4621): setSyncFinish to notify all
03-08 18:18:59.621: I/myUniqueLogTag(4621): waiting for Sync
03-08 18:18:59.621: I/myUniqueLogTag(4621): finishedWaiting!
```

so I guess one is preventing the other to run. Did they compute their `doInBackground` actually in the same Thread, and `LOCK.wait()` blocks this Thread from executing further?

Is there a way to fix it (and stay compatible to Android 2.2)?

Note:
the second Time is basically what I want, but in other Task implementations I cannot be shure that `WaitingOnLoaderTask` is only executed when the other one has finished.

Comment: "I'm trying to implement 2 Async Tasks where one should wait for the other to finish" -- why isn't it just one `AsyncTask`, then?

Comment: Or one called from `onPostExecute()` of the other, even, if you wanted to keep the tasks separate.

Comment: not possible. In "realWorld usage" the first Task is syncing things with a Server and storing the result inside a DB. its called from `Application`. The other one, recieves this data from the db, but has to wait, until the first has finished syncing, and can get called, before the sync finishes. To start the second in `onPostExecute` makes no sense, since the result will go nowhere.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html. Check order of execution part.

Comment: @RafaelT What about using a callback machanism, Creating a interface and abstract implementation in the AsyncTask...or Handler's

Comment: my proposal is to move from AsynchTask's to the custom implementations of the WorkerThreads for your purposes, I am sure that you will get rid of the your problem.

Comment: @Raghunandan thx, but `executeOnExcecutor` was added in API level 11, so I cannot use it

Comment: Try Geobits idea. API 11 and above use executeOnExcecutor.

Comment: "the first Task is syncing things with a Server and storing the result inside a DB. its called from Application" -- which means this does not need to be an `AsyncTask`. Use an ordinary `Thread`, perhaps from your own thread pool, when you do not have to update the UI.

Comment: @CommonsWare You are right, that I can use a Simple Thread. I just started implementing everythin inside AsyncTasks and wondered, why one blocks the other, because I assumed they all have their own Threads. This is what I will do, if it turns out, that AsyncTasks are sharing Threads

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to use Geobits suggestion.

You can use the onPostExecute() function to call the next Async task so it will perform it:

```
class WaitingOnLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{
    protected void onPreExecute(Void)
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    protected void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        //Commands for first AsyncTask
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void)
    {
        //Call AsyncTask 2
    }
}
```

That way it will wait until Task 1 completes.

Comment: as I already told 2 times: THIS is not possible, since the second is called on purpose from within the APP, where the first is startet inside `Application`!!!

Comment: @RafaelT : ok then first task execute as `new LoaderTask(1000, 5).execute((Void[])null).get();` now second will wait until first not completed

Comment: `AsyncTask.get` will block the `MainThread` which will cause an `ANR`

Answer (score 1):

Your code works as expected on Android 3.2 and lower. On higher Android versions AsyncTasks are not executed parallel try this to make it work on Android 4+:

```
LoaderTask loaderTask = new LoaderTask(1000, 5);
WaitingOnLoaderTask waitingTask = new WaitingOnLoaderTask();
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
    loaderTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    waitingTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
} else {
    loaderTask.execute();
    waitingTask.execute();
}
```

Note: You should mark your AsyncTasks as `static` to avoid leaking Activity on configuration change (e.g. rotation).